# how to print addition of two number using input method

Tags: python

```py
def number(num1,num2):
    num1=int(input("Enter the first number  : "))
    num2=float(input("Enter the second number : "))
    return num1, num2

def add(num1, num2):
    number(num1,num2)
    return num1+num2


#print(f'{num1}+{num2}={add(num1,num2)}')

print(add(num1,num2))
```

```
NameError: name 'num1' is not defined
```

how to print addition of two number using input method

Answer (score 2):

```
def number():
    num1 = int(input("Enter the first number  : "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number : "))
    return num1, num2

def add():
    num1, num2 = number()
    return num1 + num2
    
print(add())
```

If you want to stick with this implementation.

But this is more straigth forward :

```
def add():
    return int(input("Enter the first number  : ")) + float(input("Enter the second number : "))
print(add())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that feels more appropriate for the definition of the functions:

```
def number():
    num1=int(input("Enter the first number  : "))
    num2=float(input("Enter the second number : "))
    return num1, num2

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2

print(add(*number()))
```